# Nested Mat-table when clicked on particular row

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

I have a data source for mat-table  after binding ,when I click on a 
     particular row I need to call a particular api through angular service 
     and again bind data to datasource1 and bind it with new mat-table inside 
    the old mat-table somwhat like a nested mat-table ,I stuck on how to 
    create multiple data source becoz I dont know how many click will be done 
    by the end user ,click of particular row depends on a flag that is there 
    within the data source .Do i need to create as many data source depends 
    on click or is there a better way??

Directive for host listing the click event and toggling the data:
    I created a directive and able to bind just a simple text message on 
    click of paticular row.

I disabled the click event for mat-table row if the flag is y

Expected result:-a mat-table with multiple rows when clicked on particular 
   row, a new mat-table shoukd get attached just below the clicked row and 
   so on

My view Location Component:-

```html
  <mat-table *ngIf="showTable" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let header of displayedColumns;index as i" [matColumnDef]="header">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{header}} </mat-header-cell>
      <ng-container *ngIf=" header!='Action' ">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[header]}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf=" header=='Action' ">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat- icon(click)="
          openMoveLocation(controls.selectBu.value,controls.selectLevel.value
          ,controls.selectLocation.value)">
            redo</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="openDeleteLocation()">delete</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="openDeleteTeritory()">delete_forever</mat-icon>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row" [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl" (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

</div>

<ng-template #tpl let-element>
  <div class="mat-row" [@detailExpand] style="overflow: hidden">
    <mat-table *ngIf="showTable" #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

      <ng-container *ngFor="let header of displayedColumns;index as i" [matColumnDef]="header">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{header}} </mat-header-cell>
        <ng-container *ngIf=" header!='Action' ">
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[header]}} </mat- cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf=" header=='Action' ">
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-icon (click)="openMoveLocation
            (controls.selectBu.value,
             controls.selectLevel.value,
              controls.selectLocation.value)">
              redo</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="openDeleteLocation()">delete</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="openDeleteTeritory()">delete_forever
            </mat-icon>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row" [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl" (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Detail row directive:-

```js
import {Directive, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, Output, 
    TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from '../../services/location/location.service'

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdkDetailRow]'
})

export class CdkDetailRowDirective {
  private row: any;
  private tRef: TemplateRef < any > ;
  private opened: boolean;

  @HostBinding('class.expanded')
  get expended(): boolean {
    return this.opened;
  }

  @Input()
  set cdkDetailRow(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.row) {
      this.row = value;
      // this.render();
    }
  }

  @Input('cdkDetailRowTpl')
  set template(value: TemplateRef<any>) {
    if (value !== this.tRef) {
      this.tRef = value;
    }
  }

  @Output() toggleChange = new EventEmitter<CdkDetailRowDirective>();

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    if (this.row.FLAG != 'Y' && this.row.CNT != 'Y') {
      this.toggle();
    }
  }

  toggle(): void {
    if (this.opened) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
    } else {
      this.render();
    }
    this.opened = this.vcRef.length > 0;
    this.toggleChange.emit(this);
  }

  private render(): void {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    if (this.tRef && this.row) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef, {
        $implicit: this.row
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My view-location.ts:-

```js
onToggleChange(cdkDetailRow: CdkDetailRowDirective): void {

  this.requestParameters.ACTION = '0';
  this.requestParameters.BUCODE = this.controls.selectBu.value.CMPSEQNO;
  this.requestParameters.GEOLOCCODE = cdkDetailRow['row'].LOC_CODE;
  console.log(this.requestParameters)
  //call api through service and bind data to new data source but do i 
  // need to create 5 data source if user click 5 times 
  if (this.openedRow && this.openedRow.expended) {
    this.openedRow.toggle();
  }
  this.openedRow = cdkDetailRow.expended ? cdkDetailRow : undefined;
}
```

Expected Result:-

refer image 1 [a simple mat-table with multiple data that i achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyMvU.png)

refer image 2 [after click on any row a api call should be done and a new mat-table should bind just below the clicked row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA1SO.png)

refer image 3 [nested grid after click on inner mat-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CzyO.png)